# Can I set a default value to an input with the ng-model in my template?

Tags: angularjs

I try to achieve this:

```
<input name="formkey"
       ng-model="formkey"
       value="1_4bKU-Be3K4sMuoQTDHfz7uMqGd9N9fU6bGd1EjEu8s"
>
```

or:

```
<input type="hidden" 
       name="formkey"
       ng-model="formkey" 
       value="1_4bKU-Be3K4sMuoQTDHfz7uMqGd9N9fU6bGd1EjEu8s"
>
```

The input is empty when I look at it in a browser. If I remove `ng-model="formkey"` it works, so I assume the empty formkey-value overwrites my value.

I know I can add values to the scope with javascript. But I use this same javascript in a lot of different views, so I would much prefer to add the value in my view somehow. Is it at all possible?

Comment: have you tried `ng-init='formkey=somedefault'` ? (havent tested it)

Comment: You can use ng-init for either calling a scope function, or directly initialize the value.
    <span ng-init="formkey = 'hello'"> (html here) </span>

Answer (score 11):

`ng-init` should do the trick:

```
<input ng-init="formkey='Your default value'" />
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe the other answers are a bit incomplete.

You can achieve this with `ng-init` by linking the `ng-model` to the value you wish to set:

```
<input ng-model="formkey" ng-init="formkey='Your default value'" />
```

Answer (score 2):

set `ng-init` instead of `value`:

```
<input name="formkey"   
     ng-init = "formkey='Be3K4sMuoQTDHfz7uMqGd9N9fU6bGd1EjEu8s'"
    ng-model="formkey"
>
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/877/)**</kbd>

Comment: is there any reason to keep the value-property?

Answer (score 0):

if the default value to display in input control is a sessionStorage value then how we can initiate that value in ng-init.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.msg" ng-init="data.msg=sessionStorage('Message')"/>
```